# Jasmine on Node.js fails with ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT

Tags: node.js, jasmine

I'm writing an Express v4.18.2 app on Node.js 18.12.1 on Windows. I'm testing a controller with  Jasmine 4.5.0. When I run `jasmine spec`, it fails with an error message about resolving ES modules:

> Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import
> '...\SimpleServiceJasmine\spec' is not supported resolving ES modules
> imported from
> ...\SimpleServiceJasmine\node_modules\jasmine\lib\loader.js
> ...
> code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT',
> url: 'file:///D:/.../SimpleServiceJasmine/spec'

I use `require`, not `import`, everywhere in the code being tested or the spec.

Note that jasmine runs fine if I specify the spec file explicitly, even with wildcards, as long as the wildcard path resolves to a single file:

```
jasmine spec/service/contact-api.spec.js  # ok
jasmine spec/*/c*  # ok
```

I tried downgrading jasmine to 3.0.0 and 2.0.1 but got the same error. The behavior is the same on Windows 11 and Windows Server 2019.

Any suggestions for how can I run all the specs in this project?

Here's my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "simpleservice",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A simple CRUD API for contacts",
  "main": "service/contact-api.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "jasmine spec/service/contact-api.spec.js",
    "start": "node src/service/contact-api.js"
  },
  "author": "Puzzled Dev",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.18.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "jasmine": "^4.5.0"
  }
}
```

Here's the `spec/support/jasmine.json`:

```
{
  "spec_dir": "spec",
  "spec_files": [
    "**/*[sS]pec.?(m)js"
  ],
  "helpers": [
    "helpers/**/*.?(m)js"
  ],
  "env": {
    "stopSpecOnExpectationFailure": false,
    "random": true
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you share the `jasmine.json`?

Comment: @MostafaFakhraei I added jasmine.json

Answer (score 1):

Jasmine uses [glob](https://github.com/isaacs/node-glob) for pattern matching, which means whenever you pass `spec` as a pattern, glob finds this particular directory and then returns it to jasmine. Unfortunately, path validation in jasmine does not seem in a very smart way, it continues executing with the given path, and then it throws an error by Node.js.

It is equivalent to this:

```js
import spec from './spec'
```

You can take a look at the [jasmine-runner](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/blob/9fc487f20fee2e3f031d335afafd4c6c4c2e7aff/lib/loader.js#L22;) code, and the line in which contributor put a comment:

> *The ES module spec requires import paths to be valid URLs. As of v14,
> Node enforces this on Windows but not on other OSes. On OS X, import
> paths that are URLs **must not contain parent directory references***.

So, once you have defined `spec_files` in `jasmine.json`, there is no need to give an extra pattern to execute all tests.

`jasmine` will execute all tests with the help of `spec_dir`, and `spec_files` fields in `jasmine.json`. All you need to do is just simply run `jasmine` or `npx jasmine`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Unfortunately when I execute ```jasmine``` or ```npx jasmine```, it produces no output at all. I have very little experience with how Node modules imports are implemented, but why is Jasmine trying to import the ```spec``` directory? From what I've read, attempting to import a directory is an error. As you said, the comment in ```loader.js``` implies that imports are handled differently in Windows. This looks like a Jasmine bug that's specific to Windows; I'll submit a bug report.

Comment: Actually, as I mentioned. whenever you give `spec` as a pattern, glob gives this directory to jasmine, and jasmine simply imports it, without checking if there are any files that exist or not. Are you on windows? I'm using Linux and I can confirm `npx jasmine` works perfectly.

Comment: Yes, I'm on Windows. The message "Directory import...is not supported" seems to be related to the comment in loader.js that "Node enforces this on Windows but not on other OSs". I don't see how glob is involved here, because ```jasmine spec``` has no wildcards, so there's no globbing to be done. Jasmine is just trying import the spec folder itself, and the loader is reporting that it doesn't allow a folder to be imported.

Comment: Yes, glob is involved before Jasmine starts to execute tests. Actually, Jasmine takes the pattern and aggregates them with `spec_files` paths in `jasmine.json`. and then give them to `glob` to return all directories. [See the code](https://github.com/jasmine/jasmine-npm/blob/a8a56065157e24e36f0c6f5ce1108d6cf9eb0247/lib/jasmine.js#L566). and are you sure you feed jasmine with the `jasmine.json`?

Comment: jasmine.json is in spec/support. I get the same error if I run it as ```jasmine --config=spec/support/jasmine.json```